# Using hasOwnProperty() to reference objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to write a function in JavaScript that will apply a style object to an html element but *only* if that object exists.

Example, if I have the following object:

```
objMyObject {
    "idstring": {
        "style" : {
            "opacity": "0.50"
        }
    }
};
```

So I use **hasOwnProperty()** to first check that **"style"** exists before trying to apply it - and this works fine.

However, let's imagine that my object has multiple styles:

```
objMyObject {
    "idstring1": {
        "style" : {
            "opacity": "0.50"
        }
    },

    "idstring2": {
        "style": {
            "opacity": "0.99"
        }
    },

    "idstring3": {
        "style": {
            "opacity": "0.50"
        }
    }

};
```

Now, sometimes these individual style objects can be the same. The above examples are short but the objects can be much larger and hold multiple style properties, so it would be better if I could do something like:

```
objMyObject {
    "idstring1": {
        "style" : {
            "opacity": "0.50"
        }
    },

    "idstring2": {
        "style": {
            "opacity": "0.99"
        }
    },

    "idstring3": {
        // This particular style object has the same properties as
        // idstring1
        "apply": "idstring1"
    }

};
```

So I could then do something like this:

```
if (objMyObject.hasOwnProperty("idstring3")) {
    if (objMyObject.idString3.hasOwnProperty("apply"))
        // Apply an existing, alternative style object.
        //
        $("#el").css(objMyObject.idstring3.apply)
    else if (objMyObject.idstring3.hasOwnProperty("style"))
        $("#el").css(objMyObject.idString3.style)
}
```

The problem is that the first call to **hasOwnProperty()**:

```
if (objMyObject.hasOwnProperty("idstring3"))
```

Evaluates as true, which is great. However, subsequent calls fail even though the objects contain either a "style" or "apply" object.

Here's the full code I'm working with:

```
// JavaScript object - the "mouseout" object should apply the
// "init" object.
//
var objHeader = {
    "targetID": "header",

    "init": {
        "style": {
            "backgroundColor": "#FF0000",
            "opacity": "0.00"
        }
    },

    "load": {
        "style": {
            "opacity": "0.50"
        }
    },

    "mouseover": {
        "style": {
            "opacity": "0.99"
        }
    },

    // Here, the elApply() function should apply the "style" defined
    // in "init".
    //
    "mouseout": {
        "apply": "init"
    }
};
```

Here's the two functions I'm using:

```
// Apply a style to an object - will return false on error or true
// on success.
//
// State is the object to be applied, for example:
//
//    elApply(objHeader, "mouseout");
//
// To apply the style attached to "mouseout".
//
function elApply(
    objElement,
    objState
) {
    // Example - if elInit calls elApply(objHeader, "mouseout");
    // then will first look for objHeader.mouseout.apply, if that
    // exists then it should point to another object with a style
    // to be applied - if this is the case true is returned here
    // and all is well.
    //
    if (elApply(objElement.objState, "apply")) {
        alert("Applied 'apply' to " + objState);
        return true;
    }

    // No "apply" exists, so attempt to apply a "style"
    // object.
    //  
    if (objElement.objState.hasOwnProperty("style")) {
        $("#" + objElement.targetID).css(objElement.objState.style);
        return true;
    }

    alert("Neither '" + objState + "' nor 'apply' exist in this object!");
    return false;
}

function elInit(
    objElement
) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var targetID = objElement.targetID;         
        elApply(objElement, "mouseout");
    });
}
```

So it works like this:

1. The **elInit()** function calls **elApply(objElement, "mouseout");**
2. The **"mouseout"** property exists, and the **elApply()** function evaluates **objElement.hasOwnProperty("mouseout")** as *true*
3. Checks to see if **objElement.mouseout.apply** exists, but apparently **objElement.mouseout** is *undefined*, despite the earlier **hasOwnProperty()** call suggesting *"mouseout"* exists.

Hope this is clear, any ideas? It's not a big deal, just be neater if the objects weren't repetitive and I could re-use already defined objects.

Perhaps there's a fundamental flaw in my logic/implementation or understanding of hasOwnProperty()? If so, is there a way for sibling objects within a parent object to reference one another in such a way?

Much obliged.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a recursion issue?

Comment: Could be, the recursion was something I added trying to fix the initial problem. Maybe i should re-think this...I was thinking the issue might be because "apply" isn't an actual object, but a string...but it's still a propery of an object so was thinking perhaps a quirk with the hasOwnProperty() method. Much obliged.

Comment: If the recursive function is being called, no mater what, which happens in this case, you have an infinite looping issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to populate all missing styles in your object beforehand. Your `elStyle()` function then becomes much simpler, as it doesn't have to care about the `apply` property anymore.

Technically, copying a style from one element to another is just a copy of a reference to an object. So, it's a cheap operation.

The reason for the `do{} while()` loop in this code is to support apply 'chains' (like `mouseout0 > mouseout > init` in my example). You can safely remove it if this case is never encountered.

```js
var objHeader = {
    "targetID": "header",

    "init": {
        "style": { "backgroundColor": "#FF0000", "opacity": "0.75" }
    },
    "load": {
        "style": { "opacity": "0.50" }
    },
    "mouseover": {
        "style": { "opacity": "0.99" }
    },
    "mouseout0": {
        "apply": "mouseout"
    },
    "mouseout": {
        "apply": "init"
    }
};

function populateStyle(o) {
  var success;
  
  do {
    success = false;

    Object.keys(o).filter(
      function(k) {
        return o[k].hasOwnProperty('apply');
      }
    ).forEach(
      function(k) {
        if(o.hasOwnProperty(o[k].apply) && o[o[k].apply].hasOwnProperty('style')) {
          o[k].style = o[o[k].apply].style;
          delete o[k].apply;
          success = true;
        }
      }
    );
  } while(success);
}

function elStyle(objElement, state) {
  if(objElement.hasOwnProperty(state) && objElement[state].hasOwnProperty('style')) {
    $('#' + objElement.targetID).css(objElement[state].style);
  }
  else {
    // error: style undefined
  }
}

populateStyle(objHeader);
elStyle(objHeader, 'mouseout0');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: I have to agree...perhaps overcomplicated something that should be quite simple. Appreciate the example code, also...very nice. Much obliged.

Comment: Glad to help! I wouldn't say that you overcomplicated it. But performance wise, it's better to get rid of the complicated part from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove capital ' S ' and make small 's ' in below code.

(objMyObject.idString3.hasOwnProperty("apply"))
Replace with

(objMyObject.idstring3.hasOwnProperty("apply"))

Because JavaScript is case sensitive.

I think this will be help.

Comment: Sorry - that was just example code to help explain the problem - the real code I'm using is posted further down the OP. Sorry for the cunfusion.